# Using RSpec to test a method relying on an external Cassandra call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, cassandra

I am trying to improve the test coverage on an ActiveRecord model that creates a CSV file by querying a Cassandra database. We use RSpec. I'm having a hard time figuring out how to test the `cassandra_file` method shown below, since it calls `cdbh` (also shown below), which creates a live connection to the Cassandra database.

I tried doing something like:

```
it 'copys from cassandra' do
  cdbh = Cassandra.stub(:connect)
  date = '2013/12/27'

  expect(device).to receive(:save_csv).with(date, cdbh.execute(options))
  device.raw_file(Date.new(2013,12,27))
end
```

But I get this error:

```
Failures:

  1) Device raw_file generic device copys from cassandra
     Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `stub' for Cassandra:Module
```

I looked at some other questions dealing with stubbing API calls, but most of those suggested gems like [VCR](https://github.com/vcr/vcr) or [webmock](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock) which seem like they aren't useful for this specific use case, since I'm not trying to replicate an HTTP request. Is there a better way to test this? Is this something that's going to be reasonable to test, or is it more trouble than it's worth?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Model methods:

```
def cassandra_file(date)
  if customer.name.downcase == 'customer name'
    q = 'SELECT * FROM readings WHERE device = ? and date in (?, ?, ?)'
    return save_csv(
             date,
             cdbh.execute(q, guid, (date.to_date - 1).iso8601, date.to_date.iso8601, (date.to_date + 1).iso8601))
  else
    q = 'SELECT * FROM readings WHERE device = ? and date = ?'
    return save_csv(
             date,
             cdbh.execute(q, guid, date.to_date.iso8601))
  end
end

...

def cdbh
  return unless ENV['CASSANDRA_HOSTS']
  @cdbh ||= Cassandra.connect(hosts: ENV['CASSANDRA_HOSTS'].split(/,/)).connect('hurricane')
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion you're on the right track with stubbing--model/unit tests "should" test message-passing (while database interaction is effectively covered by integration/acceptance tests).

However I think your method, while not overly complicated, is trying to do too much, and this is impacting your ability to write clean tests. (To me the code is saying "Where do I stick this stub?," and almost kind of hammering it in there!)

One simple recommendation might be to extract some methods or even classes, as it seems that `cassandra_file` (`raw_file`?) has multiple inputs/outputs or side effects, and has become a bit tangled.

It brings to mind the *Single Responsibility Principle* from SOLID fame (though some say this [can't](http://nicksda.apotomo.de/2014/05/rails-misapprehensions-single-responsibility-principle/) be described of methods in Ruby). I'm seeing conditional query generation, a database (external system) call, and a file output. Even though it's a relatively short method, there's still a lot going on!

One current school of thought has models handling none of this--it's all POROs, "outsourced" to /lib or elsewhere, while letting ActiveRecord models be models. (So skinny controllers/fat models was considered the first step, and this may be the next.)

If you have the time and inclination I'd recommend spending more time researching this topic, as there's a number of articles as well as interesting presentations from Ruby conferences discussing it. (At the moment I'm really digging anything from [Sandi Metz](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qPfQM4w4I04).)

If not, I'd say you're close, maybe just extract a few methods as suggested and simplify the model a bit to make testing a little easier on yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough response. My goal here is to refactor this code, and do as you say and extract all the bits into separate methods. However, I'd like to have assurances that I'm not regressing functionality, and thus I would like to cover the current code with tests before attempting to take apart someone else's code. Any tips for doing that?

Comment: One thought is that if you need assurance before refactoring, you could write a "dumb" test(s) that solely verifies the normal output of the function, without introducing the complexity of stubbing the query. (In other words, why spend more time on it if it's going to change?) Slowing down your test suite a bit won't matter as much if it's temporary. Just an idea...